# Change standard selectors in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a marketing tool (Pardot) that I'm using to build forms. It creates its own markup which makes it impossible for me to apply bootstrap classes to form element, although I can create them for surrounding containers (spans/divs).

Is there a way to quickly "alias" default Boostrap classes without writing a ton of duplicate CSS for the 50 or so different form-related classes?

I've already put in some CSS, just duplicating the Boostrap CSS, but that's labor intensive and obviously won't work for Bootstrap's JavaScripts.

Comment: Not really using plain CSS, you'd need to copy all of the properties from the bootstrap classes - otherwise, if you use SASS/SCSS, you could extend the default bootstrap selectors.

Comment: I've had the same issue in Pardot and ended up switching to a custom html page (using bootstrap) and a form handler, instead of prebuilt layouts. Is this an option for you?